# Change cell background color based on value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm converting csv to html using http://derekeder.github.io/csv-to-html-table/.
I need to modify the cell background color dependent on the value of the cell. I need assistance with this, please.

```
<script>
    function format_link(link) {
        if (link >20)
        
            return "<a href='" + link + "' target='_blank'>" + link + "</a>";
            
        else return "";
    }

    CsvToHtmlTable.init({
        csv_path: "./Data/summer.csv",
        element: "table-container",
        allow_download: true,
        csv_options: {
            separator: ",",
            delimiter: '"'
        },
        datatables_options: {
            paging: true,
            processing: true
            
        },
        custom_formatting: [
            [5, format_link]
            
            
        ]
        

    });
</script>
```

i tried the format_link option but failed.

Comment: You need to pass back an HTML string - you are doing that but it’s an anchor element. Why? Try passing back a span element with style of the background color you want and with the content still being the value. And is it just for column 5 that you want to do that?

Comment: yes column 5 where i want to add the condition.

Comment: Using a plugin to turn a CSV into a table seems so cumbersome, it's pretty easy to do yourself and gain full control of the output (its just iterating over an array of arrays anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass back something like a span element which sets the color you want and has the value as its inner HTML.

And you aren't concerned with a link, but with a value so this code changes the name of that to prevent future confusion.

```
    function format_value(val) {
      if (val >20)
        return '<span style="background-color: yellow;">' + val + "</span>";      
      else return "";
}

    CsvToHtmlTable.init({
        csv_path: "./Data/summer.csv",
        element: "table-container",
        allow_download: true,
        csv_options: {
            separator: ",",
            delimiter: '"'
        },
        datatables_options: {
            paging: true,
            processing: true
            
        },
        custom_formatting: [
            [5, format_value]     
        ]
           
    });
```

Comment: Yes its working ! Many Thanks @A Haworth